# How to make something increment on a click xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i have 2 sets of vaules in a didloader and would like them to increment everytime the `IBAction` start is perfromed

here is what i have as example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super view];
    //X Speed and Y Speed
    pos = CGPointMake(2,1);
    pos2 = CGPointMake(2,1);

}


- (IBAction)start 
{

)
```

I dont mine assigning int to the 2,1 ect but the pos and pos2 values will be diffrent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increment the x and y values when the `start` method is called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super view];
    //X Speed and Y Speed
    pos = CGPointMake(2,1);
    pos2 = CGPointMake(2,1);

}


- (IBAction)start 
{
   //So you just increment their x and y values
   pos.x += 1;
   pos.y += 1;

   pos2.x += 2;
   pos2.y += 1;
}
```